# Why would this give a compile time error and not runtime error?

Tags: java

Consider this simple class:

```
public class MyClass3
{
  private int a;

  public MyClass3(int first)
  {
    this.a = first;
  }
}

public class MyClassTester
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyClass3 c1 = new MyClass3(30);
    System.out.println(c1.a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect that to give a runtime error?

Comment: Because the code is syntactically correct.

Comment: Compilers do _far_ more than just check syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *compiler* is capable of telling you that your attempt to access a private variable outside of the declaring class is invalid.  You don't have to go through the runtime to get that.

As an addendum:  the code isn't semantically valid, [per the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> - A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference type, or a constructor of a class type, is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
>   - [...] Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access is permitted **if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class** (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

If you want access to it, traditionally you use a getter for it...

```
public int getA() {
    return a;
}
```

...but if you don't want to make another method (for whatever reason), change its visibility to `public` instead.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I did not know that compilers and detect incorrect accesses as well, as in this case.

Comment: @Makoto: No; this is a smentic error, not a syntax error.

Comment: @SLaks:  Good point.  I'll rescind my remarks and  make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Because given the nature of the problem, the compiler is even unable to generate code that would run your program